# Run task once at the end in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need some task what will run at the end. Lets say some `println`. I seen multiple examples of how to run task at the end and they always depend on other task, so I don't really get how to do it and I don't have *tasks*. For now I have some piece of code:

```
if (releaseBol) 
{
 // Some of my code
 // Run twice, one for lab and other for prod
 println    fileName
}
```

That piece of code run twice, once for lab flavor and one for prod flavor in case I run:

```
MyApp:assembleRelease -PRELEASE=1
```

I need this peace of code to run only once, so for that I need to run it once at the end.

My full gradle:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def BuildNumberFile = new File('./BuildNumber.txt')
def BuildNumber = 'BRND'
def _versionName = '1.0.1'
def _applicationId = 'com.myapp.android.pic'
def _versionCode = 17
def fileName = ''
def obfuscated = false
def releaseBol = false


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    def lines = BuildNumberFile.readLines()
    BuildNumber = 'S'+lines.get(0)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId _applicationId
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode _versionCode
        versionName _versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue 'string', 'BUILD_NUMBER_RES', BuildNumber


    }

    if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE') && project.ext.RELEASE == '1')
        releaseBol = true

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}." + BuildNumber + "-" + getSvnRevision() + ".apk"))
            fileName=output.outputFile.name

        }


        variant.assemble.doLast {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                println "aligned " + output.outputFile
                println "unaligned " + output.packageApplication.outputFile

                File unaligned = output.packageApplication.outputFile;
                File aligned = output.outputFile
                if (!unaligned.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aligned.getName())) {
                    println "deleting " + unaligned.getName()
                    unaligned.delete()
                }

            }

            if (releaseBol) {

                // Some of my code
                // Run twice, one for lab and other for prod
                println fileName
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('myapp')
            storePassword "myapp123"
            keyAlias 'myapp'
            keyPassword "myappmobile"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod {


        }

        lab {

        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled obfuscated
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }


    }


    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':trunk')
}
```

It just help me if you can add some `println` to this gradle that will run once at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an instance of [`BuildListener`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html):

```
class BA extends BuildAdapter {
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
       println "finished"
    }
}

gradle.addListener(new BA())
```

**EDIT**

When it comes to `releaseBol` it can be done in the following way:

```
project.ext.releaseBol = false

class BA extends BuildAdapter {

    Project project

    BA(Project project) {
      this.project = project
    }

    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
       println "finished $project.releaseBol"
    }
}

gradle.addListener(new BA(project))
```

**EDIT 2**

You can also utilize gradle's [`TaskExecutionGraph`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html). With `whenReady` closure you can get info that the graph is ready and filled with tasks. At this time there's no option to modify the graph (add/remove task, change order) but you can (via `getAllTasks`) get the last one and... add an action. Here's how it looks like:

```
task someTask << {
  println "run"
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
  gradle.taskGraph.allTasks[-1] << {
    println 'finished'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is what I asked... but I need to put in the function BA if (releaseBol) {} and releaseBol is not reached there. I see BA runs after "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but I need it before

Comment: @Dim, you can define `releaseBol` in project scope and then refer it via `project` variable. I guess it's impossible to get it run before `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` without using a task finalizer.

Comment: @Dim, see the edit - the last one is probably what you're looking for.